# Is it possible to embed Phonegap within Native app?

Tags: android, ios, cordova

We are building a new proof of concept application which will utilise the device's camera, and I was wondering if we built this using phonegap, could we then integrate this into existing native apps ?

i.e. can you build phonegap screens, and then interact with native UI screens in Android and IOS

many thanks

Comment: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11300/phonegap-framework

Answer (score 1):

Add to your native

New Cordova-based applications created using the Xcode template provided in Cordova 1.4 or greater use Cleaver, and this template is considered the reference implementation for Cleaver.

also please follow : http://devgirl.org/2012/11/15/embed-cordovaphonegap-in-your-native-ios-app/

Comment: Phonegap Developer chat : http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11300/phonegap-framework